# UISearchBar shows wrong UIMenuItems due to use of UIMenuController elsewhere in app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar, uimenucontroller, uiresponder

I have `MyRootViewController` which presents `MyModalViewController` modally on a button press. `MyModalViewController` contains a `UISearchBar` and I want this to display the usual [Cut|Copy|Paste|Select All] text options on a long press in it’s text field.

`MyRootViewController` presents custom `UIMenuItems` (via `UIMenuController`) on a long press, hence overrides `- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder` and `- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender` and implements `-(void)duplicate:(id)sender` and `-(void)delete:(id)sender`.

The problem I have is that `MyRootViewController` is being asked which `UIMenuItems` to display for the `UISearchBar` inside `MyModalViewController`, when the user long presses inside it and is therefore displaying irrelevant menu items, instead of the usual [Cut|Copy|Paste|Select All] options for a text field.

My understanding is that this is happening because `MyRootViewController` is still in the responder chain, even though it is not currently visible.

The best solution I’ve come up with so far is to subclass `UISearchBar` and override `- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender`, returning `YES` for cut, copy, paste or Select All. This stops iOS going looking further down the responder chain. But this feels like a hack - I shouldn’t have to resort to this just to make a `UISearchBar` behave consistently with the rest of the system, just because I’m using `UIMenuController` elsewhere.

Does anyone know of a more technically correct solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to set `menuItems` property of `[UIMenuController sharedController]` only on long press. And set it to nil whenever `UIMenuControllerWillHideNotification` is thrown.